# Write an Excel table in Python

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

First of all, I tried to read out my data from an folder (it worked).

Next, I wanted to have the Animal names on the left side of the table and the names of the Owners as headings.

In the gaps between should be count of the how many off these animals everybody has.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import pandas as pd
import glob
import xlsxwriter
import xlwt

tab_data_folder = "C:\\Users\\Hanna\\Document\\Private\\Animals"
tab_files = glob.glob('%s/Names_*.tab'%(tab_data_folder))

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('table.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

for i, tab_file in enumerate(tab_files):
    df=pd.DataFrame.from_csv(tab_file, sep='\t')
    s_id = file_name[:-4].replace('Name_','')
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv(tab_file, sep='\t')

    Animal_names = ['dog', 'cat', 'bird', 'fish', 'pig', 
                    'snake', 'frog', 'monkey', 'zebra', 'sheep']

# Owner_names = tab_file

# calculates the amount of each animal 
    x = []
    number_per_animal = {}
    for b in Animal_names:    
        counter = 0
        number_per_animal[b] = 0
        for c2 in df.animal:
            if c2 == b:
                counter +=1
                number_per_animal[b] += 1
        x.append(counter)
        print ((str(b)+':'+str(x[-1]))) 


    # Add a bold format to use to highlight cells
    bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

    # Write some data headers.
    worksheet.write('B1', s_id, bold)

    # Start from the first cell below the headers.
    row = 1
    col = 0    

    # Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
    for animal, amount in zip(Animal_names,x):
        worksheet.write(row, col,     animal)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 1, amount)
        row += 1
```

Now I get my `animal_names` in the first row and the `Amount` including the data name as headline in the second row, but I have more than one item, so I want to improve this Excel file.

Now I want my programme to print all the other data as headings with the amount in the next row.  I know I need an loop or something like that but I don't know where, or how it should look.
Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: Excel files have an `xlsx` extension, *not* `xls`. `xls` is the extension for the obsolete binary format used before 2010. xlsxwriter creates xlsx files, which are zipped xml files.

Comment: Apart from that, what do you mean `I know it's wrong` ? Do you get the wrong data, or does Excel refuse to open the file?

Comment: Nothing happend and I didn't find a new file...